# Python SciPy call from terminal failing

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, terminal, scipy

I am trying to call the following Python script from the Ubuntu terminal using the standard

`python rosen.py`

but it fails. I can hit `F5` in idle and it works fine but it fails when called from the terminal. The code for `rosen.py` is as follows:

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin

def rosen(x):
    b=sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0)**2.0 + (1-x[:-1])**2.0)
    print b
    return b

x0 = [1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2]
xopt = fmin(rosen, x0, xtol=1e-8)
print xopt
```

again, when run in idle it works fine, but when called from the terminal it says that scipy doesn't exist...

I can run the following numpy code from the terminal or idle and it works fine:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.sin(1)
print a
```

It will print in either the terminal window or idle window depending where it was called.

Basically, how can I get the rosen.py to import SciPy and run when called from the Ubuntu terminal??

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: just how does it fail? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your version of `idle` is pointing at a different python implementation than the one that is first in your PATH.  Try this (from the commandline -- not python):

```
head -1 `which idle`
```

and:

```
which python
```

Are the paths the same?  If not, that's probably your problem.  To fix this, depending on your system settings, you can reorder your PATH to get the correct version of python to be called, or you could create a symbolic link to the correct python implementation somewhere very early in your path.

Comment: yes thank you mglison, when I use "head -1 'which idle' I get a return of "#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7" and when I use "which python" I get "/usr/local/bin/python" which method is easiest to correct this error?

Comment: @James you should do an `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python` .. often one directory path will point to another .. to be safe do this for the tother path too.

Comment: @James "/usr/local/bin/python" is probably a symbolic link to something else (try `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python`).  check the same thing with the `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` to make sure they really are pointing at different files.  Then to remap it, you could do:  `<sudo> mv /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python_save && ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: @James Alternatively, you could set up an alias ... in `~/.bashrc` add: `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7` -- but I wouldn't really consider this a very solid solution.

Comment: @James instead of using `python rosen.py` .. try typing the whole path and that will tell you which Python is set up correctly. e.g., `/usr/bin/python rosen.py` and the other path.

Comment: I am getting a permission denied when I attempt the sudo call... This is my own personal laptop so I can change it but not sure how...

Comment: @James Oh right, you'll probably need a `sudo` in front of both of the commands -- The first command probably already ran (check to make sure that /usr/local/bin/python is gone and /usr/local/bin/python_save exists)  If it didn't: `sudo mv /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python_save` .  Now do the second half of the command `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: So the symbolic link exists, and I changed the Python header to "#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7" and it still says that their is no module named scipy.optimize... maybe a fresh install of Python might correct it?

Comment: @James -- A fresh install + numpy + scipy should fix the problem ... If you don't have too many other modules installed that might not be a bad solution.  Ultimately, one of your python installs has scipy while another doesn't.  The trick is finding the one with it and setting up your links to point to the correct one.  you can try: `ls -l /usr/local/bin/*python*` and then for each of those, try `/usr/local/bin/XXXpythonXXX -c 'import scipy'` until you find the one that works.  Then look up symbolic links (make sure I did it properly up above ;)

Comment: Yeah for some reason they both result in no module named scipy. I'm going for the fresh install. Thank you very much for your time and help!!!

Comment: @James -- Sure, no problem.  Good luck.  Alternatively, you could just install scipy again (don't know why I didn't think of that earlier).

Comment: @James if you feel that mgilson's answer solved your problem you should consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark next to his answer (more details here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

at the top of your file to identify the location of the python interpreter? And  made your script executable with

```
chmod +x rosen.py
```

Then either command works for me under Ubuntu:

```
./rosen.py
```

or

```
python rosen.py
```

(The `chmod` is optional if you want to be able to run the script w/o typing `python` first on the command line. `python rosen.py` will work w/o the `chmod`)

And as you are already importing scipy in your script, so I am not sure I understand that part of the question.

Comment: Thank you very much Levon, I tried this method but I think the way my Python is installed is keeping me from this solution working...